# write.xlsx not saving data as dataframe

Tags: r

Consider the following code:

```
  df <- data.frame("var" = c(seq(1,10)))
  class(df)
  library(openxlsx)
  write.xlsx(df,"df.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
  library(readxl)
  df <- read_excel("df.xlsx")
  class(df)
```

It creates a dataframe `df`, save it into an excel file, and then import it. The problem is that **the imported object is not a dataframe!** The last command results in the following:

```
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

I can convert it back as dataframe, of course. But I want the object to be **saved** and **oppened** as dataframe. I can't see the problem but to me it's in the `write.xlsx` command, and can't see an option to pass to it. Any ideas what is the problem?

Comment: Its two different packages. Why not read with openxlsx?

Comment: The `class()` does like "data.frame" so it is a data.frame. It also happens to act like a tibble. What "problems" are you having with the object after you import it? If you want to store an object with all it's R class properties consider using something like `saveRDS` and `readRDS` rather than using a different exchange format.

Comment: @SmokeyShakers Well, because of path dependence. I was using readxl well before and then later on started to export as excel files. But obviously openxlsx is self-compatible.

Comment: @MrFlick command `dummies` from package `dummy` does not work. I create excel files to make my data compatible with other software (for others to use).